# The Weasel's Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

My first riddle, probably very easy but good luck!

An affiliation with dogs

My culture is like no other

Programmers use me lots

Sometimes I am with my two brothers

What am I?

HINT:

> The dogs are rubber

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I answered earlier, but I think I have a new idea... Inspired by the title actually.

> Pop. The Weasel's riddle - Pop goes the weasel. Some nursery rhyme i think.

My culture is like no other

> Pop culture.

Programmers use me lots

> Functions pop_front or pop_back.

**----EDITED----**

Sometimes I am with my two brothers

> Reference to snap, crackle and pop, three brothers from a cereal brand. Suggested by Irishpanda, Kevin, and David Starkey, thanks!

An affiliation with dogs

> Balloon animals can pop. Balloon animals are often made into dogs.

Other suggestions:

> popCORN -> CORNdogs suggested by hexomino sounds reasonable. pup being close to pop suggested by kaine, but an earlier comment that the dogs aren't real might cross that off.

Comment: The answer is correct, the dogs and brothers are wrong however, if you can get those I'll give you the tick. (Hint the brothers share a bowl)

Comment: Yeah I was really unsure about those two parts :) I'll give it a think-over.

Comment: Think cereal :)

Comment: @PiotrPytlik not sure how to to do a spoiler in comments but this link will take you to what I think is the brothers part.  http://bit.ly/1ocCj8e

Comment: One clue left to solve!

Comment: And you're initial guess for the two brothers clue applies under the programmers clue.

Comment: Snap, Crackle, and Pop are the brothers for Rice Krispies. Programmers also use something called a Stack which involves pushing items on and POPping them off.

Comment: I'd thought the "programmers use me lots" was a reference to the stereotype of drinking a lot of soda (especially Mountain Dew or other highly caffeinated sodas).

Comment: Could the affiliation with dogs be "corn" as in "popcorn" and "corndogs"?

Comment: You don't mean because pop sounds kind of like pup (puppy) do you?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I think this answer is what you were looking for.

Comment: An affiliation with dogs: Dog in the mechanical sense. "Popping the clutch" = Engaging the clutch dogs while the vehicle is in motion.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this is a wild guess, but I think the answer is

> Dot

An affiliation with dogs

> Dot = Spot, a common name for dogs

My culture is like no other

> It is regarded as good culture, proper to end sentences with a dot.

Programmers use me lots

> Dots are commonly used in many programming languages.

Sometimes I am with my two brothers

> Probably dot-dot-dot ... or colon and semicolon ; :

Comment: Great guess, unfortunately not the intended answer, here's a hint, the dogs aren't real!

Answer (score 6):

Is the answer

> Ducks

An affiliation with dogs

> Donald Duck is affiliated with Goofy, Pluto, etc.

My culture is like no other

> As a cartoon character, they have a very interesting culture indeed

Programmers use me lots

> Rubber duck debugging

Sometimes I am with my two brothers

> Refers to the Disney Brothers (Walt and Roy)

Comment: Wrong unfortunately, another good guess! some matches are a little far fetched (are there three warner brothers? I have no clue)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre - I thought this was areference to the Animaniacs, not the actual Warners.  Although that matches user18967's answer better, since this one is talking about Disney characters, not WB, and Dot does have 2 brothers...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Oops, I meant the Disney Brothers (as in Walt and Roy); Warner was a slip (I was probably thinking of Daffy)... thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Though not the OP's intended answer, I think Mouse (as in Mickey Mouse) would fit this explanation even better.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't quite get the "My culture is like no other" part, but otherwise:

The answer is

> Tails

An affiliation with dogs

> Dogs have tails

Programmers use me lots

> Tail recursion

Sometimes I am with my two brothers

> Sonic (the Hedgehog), Knuckles and Tails

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> Counter

An affiliation with dogs

> Counter surfing is when a dog steals food from the counter

My culture is like no other

> Counter culture is a culture that is very different from mainstream society

Programmers use me lots

> To keep track of iterations

Sometimes I am with my two brothers

> Posibly variable declaration and termination condition in C-style loops?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the question has already been answered though one or two of the clues are not correct, feel free to help with that one!

Great job thinking of counter culture by the way!

Answer (score 1):

For the last line: ?

> In the alphabet, O's brother would be P.